# GitHub Rest Api SHA of file that contains special characters

Tags: google-apps-script, github-api, sha

**Main issue**

This code works, but the `areReallyEqual` should not be necessary. In fact it is *not* necessary for files that don't contain special characters ("ñ", "é", "à", etc), so: all of my files except for 2 of them.

```
if (internalFileTextSha !== repositoryFile.sha) {
  // The sha might not be equal due to special characters in the text ("ñ", "é", "à", etc)... doing a second check...
  const remoteFileText = this._gitHubApi.fetchGitHubGetUrl(repositoryFile.download_url).getContentText(); 
  const remoteFileTextSha = GitHubCrypto.getSha(remoteFileText);
  const areReallyEqual = remoteFileTextSha === internalFileTextSha;
  if(!areReallyEqual) {
    // The file has been modified, creating a new commit with the updated file...
    this._gitHubApi.commitUpdatedFile(repositoryName, repositoryFile, internalFile.source);
  } else {
    // The second check determined that both files were equal
  }         
}
```

---

**More details**

`internalFile` comes from here:

```
  /**
  * @typedef {Object} InternalFile
  * @property {string} id - The ID of the internal file.
  * @property {string} name - The name of the internal file.
  * @property {string} type - The type of the internal file.
  * @property {string} source - The source code of the internal file.
  */

  /**
   * Gets all the internal files of a Google Apps Script file.
   *
   * @returns {InternalFile[]} An array of objects.
   */
  static getScriptInternalFiles(file) {
    // Check that the file is a Google Apps Script file
    if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.script') {
      // Get the script content as a string
      const fileId = file.getId();
      const params = {
        headers: { 
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
          'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
        },
        followRedirects: true,
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
      };
      const url =
        'https://script.google.com/feeds/download/export?id='
        + fileId
        + '&format=json';
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      const json = JSON.parse(response);
      return json.files;  
    } else {
      throw new Error("The file is not a Google Apps Script file.");
    }
  }
```

...while `remoteFile` comes from here:

```
  /**
  * @typedef {Object} RepositoryFile
  * @property {string} name - The name of the file.
  * @property {string} path - The file path in the repository.
  * @property {string} sha - The SHA hash of the file.
  * @property {Number} size - The size of the file in bytes.
  * @property {string} url - The URL of the file's contents.
  * @property {string} html_url - The URL to the file's page on the repository website.
  * @property {string} git_url - The URL to the file's git contents.
  * @property {string} download_url - The URL to download the file.
  * @property {string} type - The type of the file, usually "file".
  */

  /**
   * Gets all the internal files of a Google Apps Script file.
   *
   * @returns {RepositoryFile[]} An array of objects.
   */
  listFilesInRepository(repositoryName) {
    let repositoryFiles = [];
    try {
      const options = {
        headers: {
          ...this._authorizationHeader,
        },
      };      
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${this._buildRepositoryUrl(repositoryName)}/contents`, options);
      repositoryFiles = JSON.parse(response);
    } catch(e) {
      const errorMessage = GitHubApi._getErrorMessage(e);
      if(errorMessage === 'This repository is empty.') {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        // unknown error
        throw e;
      }
    }
    return repositoryFiles;
  }
```

...and the SHA calculation:

```
class GitHubCrypto {
  /**
   * @param {string} fileContent
   * @returns {string} SHA1 hash string
   */
  static getSha(fileContent) {
    // GitHub is computing the sum of `blob <length>\x00<contents>`, where `length` is the length in bytes of the content string and `\x00` is a single null byte.
    // For the Sha1 implementation, see: www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html
    const sha = Sha1.hash('blob ' + fileContent.length + '\x00' + fileContent);
    return sha;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your question, for example, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike : for a file that contains the following text: 'ñèàü', the result is `internalFileSha ('430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4') != repositoryFile.sha ('56c9357fcf2589619880e1978deb8365454ece11')`. 

This problem does not happen if the file text does not contain special characters (let's say `fileText = 'aaaa'`, then `sha = '7c4a013e52c76442ab80ee5572399a30373600a2'` for both). 

Plus with 'ñèàü' if instead of trusting `remoteFile.sha` I fetch the contents of the from GitHub and then compute the sha, the result is the expected one (`'430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4'`).

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of `aaaa`, when I tested it with your provided URL https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html , the hash value is `70c881d4a26984ddce795f6f71817c9cf4480e79`. So, can I ask you about the logic for obtaining `7c4a013e52c76442ab80ee5572399a30373600a2`? And also, when I tested `ñèàü` with your provided URL, `e8e008057764470309752185b7bd46fa6f9f737f` is returned. It seems that this is different from your value of `430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4`.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for testing it. I applied a "direct sha" on 'aaaa' using [this code](www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) (which is the code I use in my program) and I get '7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a6a91462a815' (which is different than your result). But GitHub  does not a "direct sha", instead it computes the sha like so: `const sha = Sha1.hash('blob ' + fileContent.length + '\x00' + fileContent);`, which of course leads to a different result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a6a91462a815` from `aaaa`, unfortunately, when I tested it again, I got `70c881d4a26984ddce795f6f71817c9cf4480e79` from `aaaa`. But, when I used `aaa`, `7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a6a91462a815` is obtained. How about this?

Comment: About `430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4` you expected, in this case, you want to retrieve it from `'blob ' + fileContent.length + '\x00' + fileContent` where `fileContent` is `ñèàü`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It is indeed weird that 'aaa' yelds for you the same result that for me does 'aaaa'... What I can say is that when I apply it on 'blob 4\x00aaaa' I get the same result as GitHub's sha. About your last comment (regarding '430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4 ' ), this is correct, it is the result I obtain from: `SHA1('blob 4\x00ñèàü')`, which is different from GitHub's sha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem... the problem was in the "bytes length":

GitHub is computing the sum of `blob <length>\x00<contents>`, where `length` is the length in bytes of the content string and `\x00` is a single null byte.

When there are no special characters, `lengthInBytes == inputStr.length`, but when there are special characters this is no longer true:

```
// For the Sha1 implementation, see: www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html

function simpleShaTest1() {
  const fileContent = 'ñèàü';
  const expectedSha = '56c9357fcf2589619880e1978deb8365454ece11';
  const sha = Sha1.hash('blob ' + byteLength(fileContent) + '\x00' + fileContent);
  const areEqual = (sha === expectedSha); // true
}

function simpleShaTest2() {
  const fileContent = 'aaa';
  const expectedSha = '7c4a013e52c76442ab80ee5572399a30373600a2';
  const sha = Sha1.hash('blob ' + lengthInUtf8Bytes(fileContent) + '\x00' + fileContent);
  const areEqual = (sha === expectedSha); // true
}

function lengthInUtf8Bytes(str) {
  // Matches only the 10.. bytes that are non-initial characters in a multi-byte sequence.
  var m = encodeURIComponent(str).match(/%[89ABab]/g);
  // `m` is `null` when there are no special characters, thus returning `m.length`
  return str.length + (m ? m.length : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the has value of `430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4` from a value of `ñèàü` using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fileContent = 'ñèàü'; // This is from your comment.

  const value = 'blob ' + fileContent.length + '\x00' + fileContent;
  const bytes = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, value, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  const res = bytes.map(byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
  console.log(res); // 430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4
}
```

- When this script is run, the has value of `430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4` is obtained.
- When `aaaa` is directly used like `const res = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, "aaaa", Utilities.Charset.UTF_8).map(byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')`, `70c881d4a26984ddce795f6f71817c9cf4480e79` is obtained.

#### Reference:

- [computeDigest(algorithm, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value_1)

Comment: Here you obtain the same result as I do for the input 'ñèàü' ('430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4'), instead of GitHub's result which is different (and I can't figure out why) --> `repositoryFile.sha` is '56c9357fcf2589619880e1978deb8365454ece11'. For 'aaaa' your result and GitHub's is the same (as in my code as well).

Comment: @Xavier Peña Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. And, I cannot understand whether my proposed answer resolved your question that you wanted to obtain `430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4` from `'blob ' + fileContent.length + '\x00' + fileContent` where `const fileContent = 'ñèàü'`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: Your English is perfect ! And thanks for trying to understand the issue I am having. Here is the summary: `inputStr1 =  'ñèàü'`, `GitHubSHA(inputStr1 ) == '56c9357fcf2589619880e1978deb8365454ece11'`, `MySHA(inputStr1 ) == YourSHA(inputStr1 ) == '430f370909821443112064cd149a4bebd271bfc4' != GitHubSHA(input)`. And here is why it is also important to test `InputStr = 'aaaa'`: when there are no special characters (like in `inputStr2 = 'aaaa'`) then `MySHA(inputStr2 ) == GitHubSHA(inputStr2 )`. My question is: what does GitHub does to calculate the SHA when the input contains special characters?

Comment: The discussion with you helped me find the solution (see answer below). Thank you so much, I was completely stuck. And of course you were right about 'aaa' instead of 'aaaa', I didn't realize.